# Convertion of textbox value to single adds extra precision in C#

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, decimal, numerics

While converting value of a textbox to `Convert.ToSingle()` adds some extra precision for values like 2.7 to 2.7999999523162842. I don't want any rounding of this value because I have to store the exact value entered by the user to DB. So if any one have this issue before please post the solution, any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's because a [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) is a [binary fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Fractions) which cannot exactly represent the number 2.7 -- when you try to assign a number that is not a binary fraction to a `float` or a `double`, you will inevitably end up with an inexact representation.

You need use a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) if you don't want to precise represent decimal numbers like 2.7.

```
var myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(input);
```

SImilarly, to store this value in a sql server database you need to use a SQL data type capable of storing precise decimal numerics. Conventiently, this data type is called [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) in SQL as well